# Qual é a diferença entre Meter e Progress no HTML5?

Tags: html, html5

Qual é a diferença dessas duas tags html, apenas a aparência(layout,cor) é diferente?

```
<meter min="0" max="100" value="22"></meter>

<progress value="22" max="100"> </progress>
```

Qual é a diferença da `meter` e `progress` ? sendo que aparentimente elas tem o mesmo propósito e objetivo?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

De acordo com [está resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6552147/1608936) no *SOEn* não há muita diferença entre a utilização entre uma ou outra. Basicamente a tag `<progress>` é usada para exibir o andamento de uma tarefa específica(eg: *informar o usuário sobre o andamento do seu pedido ou tarefa, importação de dados, etc*), enquanto a tag `<meter>` tem bom uso por exemplo, em exibir a utilização do disco ou a relevância do resultado de uma consulta.

Veja [**este gráfico**](http://peter.sh/examples/?/html/meter-progress.html) onde exibe a diferença entre elas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 10):

Apesar de serem parecidas visualmente elas tem diferentes propósitos, vejamos:

`<progress>`: representa o progresso da realização de uma tarefa, exemplo: upload de um arquivo.

`<meter>` representa uma medida, por exemplo de **uso de disco**, relevância do resultado de uma consulta, ou a fração de uma população que votou num candidato em particular.

Fontes: [1](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html#the-progress-element), [2](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html#the-meter-element)